# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. Unable to determine where to place exclusions

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j, slf4j

First off I feel really thick. I have looked at stack as well as other resources and I cannot figure out the solution to my problem. Any help is appreciated.

When executing my tests I see get the following prior to my actual test running.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse%20-%20BDD.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Applications/Eclipse%20-%20BDD.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/6/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Applications/Eclipse%20-%20BDD.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Applications/Eclipse%20-%20BDD.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/6/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

I ran mvn dependency:tree

Output is:

```
    > [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ TopGolfAutomtionSuite ---
    [INFO] TopGolfAutomtionSuite:TopGolfAutomtionSuite:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
    [INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.8.15:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
    [INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.0-jre:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.10.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.14.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.17:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.17:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.17:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile
    [INFO] +- com.aventstack:extentreports:jar:3.1.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.23:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.3.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.3.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.3.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.9.2:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.0:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
    [INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
    [INFO] +- io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar:4.3.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:3.0.6:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:3.0.6:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
    [INFO] |  +- io.rest-assured:json-path:jar:4.3.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:3.0.6:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:jar:4.3.2:test
    [INFO] |  \- io.rest-assured:xml-path:jar:4.3.2:test
    [INFO] |     +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
    [INFO] |     |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
    [INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.3:test
    [INFO] +- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.19.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.19.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.19.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
    [INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
    [INFO] |  |     |     +- nekohtml:xercesMinimal:jar:1.9.6.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |     |     +- nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.6.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |     |     \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6:runtime
    [INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-webdav:jar:1.5.0:runtime
    [INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-jcr-commons:jar:1.5.0:runtime
    [INFO] |  |     |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.5.3:runtime
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
    [INFO] |  |     |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |        \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.19.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.3:compile
    [INFO] +- com.github.javafaker:javafaker:jar:0.12:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.github.mifmif:generex:jar:1.0.2:compile
    [INFO] |     \- dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8:compile
    [INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
    [INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.6:provided
    [INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.testng:testng:jar:7.4.0:compile
    [INFO] |     +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.78:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.webjars:jquery:jar:3.5.1:compile
    [INFO] +- com.vimalselvam:cucumber-extentsreport:jar:3.1.1:compile
    [INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-messages:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:messages:jar:17.1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:4.0.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:13.0.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:7.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:html-formatter:jar:17.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- io.cucumber:create-meta:jar:6.0.1:compile
    [INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.7:compile
    [INFO] \- io.cucumber:gherkin:jar:22.0.0:compile




My POM.XML 

>   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <!-- Dependencies required for Project -->
    <!-- Dependencies can be updated by changing the version number -->
    <!-- Dependencies are located at https://mvnrepository.com/ -->

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Start Dependencies required for TDD project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.testng</groupId> <artifactId>testng</artifactId> 
            <version>6.14.3</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Random Name Generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Dependencies required for TDD project -->

        <!-- Start Dependencies required for BDD project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- END Dependencies required for BDD project -->

    </dependencies>
```

Again any help is appreciated. From what I have read I need to add some exclusions but Im not sure where.
E.g.

```
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea. But the problem is inside eclipse and not your project. Try running from the CLI without Eclipse.

Comment: The log implementations act as plug-in fragments to the API plug-in, so your configuration needs to have only one.